# neo4j find who has acted in all of the movies that someone acts in

Tags: neo4j, cypher, database, nosql

I use database cineasts(actor and movie). It has relationship (:ACTOR)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie). Now I want to find the actors who has acted in **all of the movies** that actor "abc" acts in.

My idea is first to get the movie collection of "abc" using WITH COLLECT. Then using ALL() to find the required actors. But I am not sure how to write the filter in ALL(). How to write it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Neo4j knowledge base article on [performing match intersection](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/).

The kind of queries you're looking for are going to be similar.

For example, using the first technique mentioned, we can do something like this:

```
MATCH (abc:Actor{name:'abc'})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH abc, collect(distinct m) as movies
WITH abc, movies, size(movies) as movieCnt
UNWIND movies as m
MATCH (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a:Actor)
WHERE abc <> a
WITH a, collect(distinct m) as commonMovies, movieCnt
WHERE size(commonMovies) = movieCnt
RETURN a
```

If you wanted to use the alternate approach with ALL(), it might look like this:

```
MATCH (abc:Actor{name:'abc'})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH abc, collect(distinct m) as movies
WITH abc, movies, head(movies) as first
MATCH (first)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a:Actor)
WHERE abc <> a AND ALL(m in movies WHERE (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a))
RETURN a
```

We start the match from the first of the movies collection so we start from a relevant set of :Actors instead of having to filter starting from all :Actor nodes. That can be improved further if we sort the movies by the number of actors ascending first, since that will lead to the narrowest starting pool of coactors.